# Search and sort directory and subdirectory using Batch Script

Tags: search, sorting, batch-file

I have been trying to do a search of the user directory and subdirectories in a primary school for all applications, music, videos and archived files to check what the kids are hiding from me. I have been using a basic dir script similar to this:

```
dir C:\Sample\*.exe, C:\Sample\*.rar, C:\Sample\*.mp3  /s /b /OE > D:\Result.txt
```

This provides me with an output of ALL files of those types sorted by user name.

What I want to know is, is there an easy way to either change the search to sort by type or to use the sort command afterwards to sort by the last character/s of the file.

Sample of output:

```
U:\adwan4\My Documents\My Videos\PhotoStory1.wmv
U:\ageeg2\My Documents\install_flashplayer11x32ax_gtbp_chra_aih.exe
U:\amcka55\My Documents\My Music\Angus.wmv
```

I have come up with something that appears to do the trick using Find along the lines of:

```
Find ".exe" D:\Result.txt >>D:\Sorted.txt
```

This appears to work fine for the avi, exe, etc. However I would be very happy for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
for %%x in (exe,mp3) do (
for /r C:\Dir %%a in (*.%%x) do echo %%a >>D:\Results.txt
)
```

Comment: Basically I want it to show by extension, so that the sample I provided would show up as:

    `U:\ageeg2\My Documents\install_flashplayer11x32ax_gtbp_chra_aih.exe`
    `U:\adwan4\My Documents\My Videos\PhotoStory1.wmv`
    `U:\amcka55\My Documents\My Music\Angus.wmv`

Something like that

Comment: Ok, so you want to sort by extension? Like show all the exe's, then all the mp3's etc

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :) Try my script, it should do exactly that.

Comment: I tried it and it is still sorted by directory. Having run it the first 6 are exes followed by some mp3s, then some more exes etc. Thanks a lot. I really do appreciate your help, I'm currently learning some bat scripting through trial and error.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I was just testing on one directory so my tests would have made me think it was working, hang on a sec and I will update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, just tag on any extensions you need to add separated by a comma, and remember to rename or delete the old results file as it will append as it goes along, so if it's already there it will add the results to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it work nicely. It is a much more elegant solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, my initial solution (which took a lot more typing because it has no loops) looks something like this:

```
ECHO Off
dir U:\*.exe, U:\*.rar, U:\*.mp3  /s /b > D:\Result.txt
Echo Applications > D:\Sorted.txt
Echo --------------------------- >>D:\Sorted.txt
Find ".exe" D:\Result.txt >>D:\Sorted.txt
Echo Music >> D:\Sorted.txt
Echo --------------------------- >>D:\Sorted.txt
Find ".mp3" D:\Result.txt >>D:\Sorted.txt
Echo --------------------------- >>D:\Sorted.txt
Find ".wma" D:\Result.txt >>D:\Sorted.txt
```

etc

A lot more work to setup and is a 2 step process. The solution doesn't look as elegant as either option presented to me either. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for making the effort to do it yourself, sometimes a rare thing on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

The DIR /O sort option works fine when run without the /S option. But when you use the /S option it sorts the results within each directory individually, whereas you want to sort the entire result set.

Bali C's edited answer solves the problem by performing multiple searches individually, one per file extension. He chose to use the FOR command to iterate the files and ECHO the results. I believe it is simpler just to use multiple DIR commands.

```
>d:result.txt (
  dir /s /b C:\Sample\*.exe
  dir /s /b C:\Sample\*.rar
  dir /s /b C:\Sample\*.mp3
)
```

or, perhaps a bit less typing

```
>d:result.txt (
  for %%X in (exe rar mp3) do dir /s /b C:\Sample\*.%%X
)
```

Comment: The main worry I have about this is that since the script isn't aimed at C:\Sample (that was just so I could test it) but is actually aimed at the user directory on the server that running multiple dir commands can take quite a while to run. I didn't realise how flexible batch scripting actually is.